# Get largest unsigned integer type

Tags: c++, c++11

I need a way to get the largest type available on the target compiler architecture. I'd expect a define along the lines of:

```
#if defined PLATFORM_32BIT
#define LARGEST_UNSIGNED_TYPE uint32_t
#elseif defined PLATFORM_64BIT
#define LARGEST_UNSIGNED_TYPE uint64_t
#endif
```

Is there a standard C++ way to achieve this? Or do I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can use `uint64_t` you should also be able to use [`uintmax_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Answer (score 3):

Header `<cstdint>`in C++ (and `<stdint.h>` in C) already contains the following definitions

`typedef` *signed integer type* `intmax_t;`

and

`typedef` *unsigned integer type* `uintmax_t;`

Comment: get largest _unsigned_ integer type

Comment: @stefan Do not hurry.

Comment: I could say the same to you ;-) If you plan on including the relevant information, why not wait until you've written everything before posting? :D